# facebook comments on each post?

Tags: facebook, blogs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I'm writing a blog in php, and when I was going to add comments, I figured nobody would want to have to register on my blog to post comments, so I decided to try facebook comments.

I found the comments box, but as far as I read, I'll have one box for all my posts. I want to know how do I make different comments for each post I make?

posts url layout is like http://xxxxxxx.com/post.php?postid=1 , postid=2 and so on.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

To create unique comment boxes dynamicly i use $_SERVER request for php.
This sample uses the html5 version of the comment box, same can be done with the xfbml version as well.

```
<?php
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

Comment: Rafael, if you could please mark the answer as correct so that other users may find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net Solution

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href='<% GetUrl();%>' data-width="700" style="direction:ltr">
 </div>
```

in Cs File Write GetUrl Function

```
  public string GetUrl()
  {
            return string.Format("http://www.sample.com/Content.aspx?id={0}",requset.q Request.QueryString["id"]);
  }
```